# How to find the path of a running process using the process id? (windows)

Tags: python, file

I have a little script that scans the opened windows, when it founds a word doc opened it has to get the path to the file. But how ? I searched a lot but nothing seems to work. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
from ctypes import *
import sys
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import win32gui
import win32clipboard
import os
import shutil
import time

user32   = windll.user32
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
psapi    = windll.psapi
current_window = None


def get_current_process():
    global current_window
    global process_id
    # get a handle to the foreground window
    hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()

    # find the process ID
    pid = c_ulong(0)
    user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, byref(pid))

    # store the current process ID
    process_id = "%d" % pid.value

    # grab the executable
    executable = create_string_buffer("\x00" * 512)
    h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(0x400 | 0x10, False, pid)

    psapi.GetModuleBaseNameA(h_process,None,byref(executable),512)

    # now read it's title
    window_title = create_string_buffer("\x00" * 512)
    length = user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, byref(window_title),512)

    # print out the header if we're in the right process

    print("\n")
    print("[ PID: %s - %s - %s ]" % (process_id, executable.value, window_title.value))
    print("\n")



while True:
    get_current_process()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Have you tried psutil package .exe() method for Process objects. Check this out : https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, the MODULEENTRY32 struct contains szModule which is module name and szExePath is the full path

```py
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = windll.kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
def GetModulePath(PID,ModuleName):
    hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( 0x00000008, PID );
    me32 = MODULEENTRY32()
    me32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32)
    Module32First( hModuleSnap, byref(me32))
    path = None
    while True:
        if (me32.szModule.lower()==ModuleName.lower()):
            path=me32.szExePath
            break
        if not Module32Next(hModuleSnap, byref(me32)):
            break
    CloseHandle(hModuleSnap)
    return path
```